# Get selected content in a number input when click

Tags: input, onclick, numbers

I guess is not too much difficult but your help will be useful as always.

I had before a text input where the user if click in it select all the content from this input to be able to replace faster his content like in the next example:

```
<input type="text" value="whatever" onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)">
```

So, my question will be, how can I do the same behaviour in a numeric input like the next one?

```
<input type="number" value="1111">
```

I tried to add obviously this `onclick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)"` but seems only to work on the text inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, was easy.

I found this solution that works good.

```
<input type="number" value="111" onclick="this.select();">
```